# No Route Matches - Devise User ID in Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to put the user id's from Devise within my application's routes. e.g.
(www.test.com/users/1/offers)

My application works fine but I'm getting route matching errors when trying to call a redirect_to within my controller which doesn't have a 'user'.

**Error**

> No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"offers",
>   :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_id]

**welcome_controller.rb (Doesn't need the user to be logged in)**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @skip_footer = true
    if user_signed_in?
        redirect_to user_offers_path(@user)
    else

    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 devise_for :users
 resources :users do
    resources :offers do
      member do
         put :tourcomplete
      end   
    end
  end
```

Any help would be brilliant!

EDIT

Controller

```
  def index
    if current_user.present?
      @offers = Offer.all
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end

    def tourcomplete
      current_user.update_attributes(tourcomplete: true)
      redirect_to root_url
    end

    @featured_offers = Offer.where(featured: true)

  end
```

**Category Controller**

```
resources :categories, only: :show
```

Comment: How you get the @user variable ?

Comment: Would posting rake routes help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I must point out that you're not calling a `Devise` user ID in this case, you're just using standard Rails resource routing:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :categories do #-> url.com/users/:user_id/categories
     get :test, on: :collection
   end
   resources :offers do #-> url.com/users/:user_id/offers
      put :tourcomplete #-> you don't need member do
   end
end

#app/controllers/offers_controller.rb
class OffersController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      @offers = @user.offers
   end
end
```

This is how your code *should* be used.

---

Thus if you wanted to use it with the `Welcome` controller, you'd be able to use it as follows:

```
#app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
      redirect_to user_offers_path(current_user) if user_signed_in? 
   end
end
```

---

Your `offers` controller could be improved as follows:

```
#app/controllers/offers_controller.rb
class OffersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
      @offers = Offer.all
   end
end
```

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the answer. I've added my offers controller to the question. Would this still work? Because users don't own the offers.

Comment: Perfect Answer Rich. Thanks very much!

Comment: Would you mind if I wrote a blog post about this and link back to this question?

Comment: Sure! You could write a post about my custom error pages gem too if you wanted - http://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler :-p

Comment: No problem on the answer, writing code is the simple part compared to knowing how it all works

Comment: Will do. Getting this when an 'not logged in' user tries to get to '/offers' (No route matches [GET] "/offers")

Comment: Looks like a routing issue, try the following: `#config/routes.rb resources :offers`

Comment: Is there anyway to change it to /u/? instead of users?

Comment: Sure - `resources :users, path: "u"`

Comment: Apologies for the 1,000 questions. But is there anyway to put it into my category routes as well? (Added to the question)

Comment: Put what into your category routes?

Comment: Hi Rick, I'm currently getting this error undefined method `user_tourcomplete_offer_path'?

Answer (score 1):

You can to add a `before_action` in your controller, which will fetch the `@user` you need, in order to be able to redirect to `user_offers_path(@user)`.

Something like :

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:index]

  def index
    @skip_footer = true
    if user_signed_in?
        redirect_to user_offers_path(@user)
    else

    end
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Of course, you'll also need to put the user_id in the GET or POST params when calling the index of WelcomeController.

Comment: The index for this page unfortunately doesn't need a user to be 'logged in' as it's the landing page. So it will never find anything with user.find?

Comment: You can get all Users without be logged in, but you can't get the 'current_user' devise helper without logged in.

Comment: If the user isn't logged in, you won't be able to user `redirect_to user_offers_path(@user)` because you can't get the `@user` from nowhere

Comment: Nelson Patricien Jimenez is Right. What you seem to need is the `current_user` method from Devise, which won't get you anything if the user isn't connected.

Comment: Is there anyway I can still redirect the user to that page? If they're logged in?

Comment: For `user_offers_path` : no. But yo ucan create `offers_path`. Just create another route for offers which is not nested under user.